# why i get a bad gateway error when trying to access U1 contact's webUI?

Tags: ubuntu-one, ubuntu-website

WebUI in one.ubuntu.com works well for notes and files.
Everything syncs fine and i can modify everything without problems.
Also the status page of U1 servers says everything is OK. 
But when i'm trying to access the contacts tab i get this error :

*504 Gateway Time-out
The server didn't respond in time.*

This happens for the past week or so ...

Answer (score 1):

looks like problems with your connection ( page loads fine here ). Can you check it trough some proxy ( opera turbo should work too ).

have you tried it with other dns servers ?

Comment: i tried with other dns servers. the error is random, i'm still looking into it

Comment: "traceroute archive.ubuntu.com" works ?

Comment: This problem is entirely due to slow IP communication between computers on the website, possibly including the web server. Only those who shaped the network on the site or that hosts the web server or the network admins can solve this problem.